# How to specify the engine version when creating a docker-machine on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker-machine

I would like to create a docker-machine on AWS EC2 via the `create` command. The command looks something like this:

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2  --amazonec2-region eu-central-1 my-machine
```

However this seems to always install the latest version of the engine which is kind of unpredictable, especially as the docker team is moving fast. So I would like to specify a specific version to install e.g. 1.13.1.

This is possible when installing via the virtualbox driver with the help of the `--virtualbox-boot2docker-url` parameter. I can't find any equivalent for the AWS driver.

Is this even possible at all?

Comment: Not the best solution but maybe a solution at all: Create an EC2 instance having the desired Docker version installed. Create an AMI from it and specify it using the AWS Driver for Docker-Machine using the `--amazonec2-ami` option.

Comment: It seems like this is now possible. [SvenDowideit pointed me to a possible solution](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1702#issuecomment-314411175). So there is an option for `docker-machine create` called `--engine-install-url`. But until recently that wasn't very useful because Docker itself does not provide a repository with previous versions of the install script to use. Thankfully rancher does provide such a [list for all previous versions](https://github.com/rancher/install-docker). So this should basically work. Haven't had the time to verify this myself but looks promising.